# How to make seq() work inside filter() in dplyr for sqlite database?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use seq() function (from "base") to filter a table in sqlite database.

The following code shows the problem.
What should I do to make the function work inside the filter?

```
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)

db <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

copy_to(db, mtcars, name = "mtcars", overwrite = TRUE)


# DOES NOT WORK: 
#-----------------------------------------------------
data <- tbl(db, "mtcars") %>%
  filter(cyl %in% seq(from = 4, to = 6, by = 1))

# Error: near "AS": syntax error
# In addition: Warning message:
# Named arguments ignored for SQL seq
#-----------------------------------------------------


# WORKS
#-----------------------------------------------------
data <- tbl(db, "mtcars") %>%
  filter(cyl %in% 4:6)
#-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `data <- tbl(db, "mtcars") %>% filter(cyl %in% base::seq(from = 4, to = 6, by = 1))`

Comment: Thank you Dij. This answers my question